# 'Unstoppable' service worker in PWA?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to write an offline web app, and now I have a lot of code, working like this:

```
recursiveTimeout = setTimeout(function showNotification(){
    // Here is much logic and work with indexeddb
    // registration.showNotification(...)
    recursiveTimeout = setTimeout(showNotification, interval)
}, 0)
```

I thought if I put this code in a service worker, it would be working endlessly. I was wrong :) Service Worker's lifespan is too short. But I need it to not stop. So the question is, can I use PWA for my purpose? I need any platform for this code, but JS is the only language I know.

Answer (score 0):

Service workers will stop executing shortly after their done doing work and be restarted when a new event is ready for them. You can not change this. If you need to perform persistent on-device work you will have to go with an native app or an app wrapper like [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/).